# Ligatures in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

we are working on an icon font that will have an ultimate collection of glyphs and will be available for free http://www.webhostinghub.com/glyphs/
We think that the easiest way to use it is with ligatures and not through elaborate CSS just like many other projects do. The problem is that it doesn't seem that the ligatures do not seem to work in Internet Explorer. They do work just fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but not in IE.

That is a shame, since it is Microsoft who was the first to use @font-face but for some reason they forget that fonts may have ligatures. Or maybe I am mistaken and I hope I am mistaken and there is some magic way to make them work. I would be very grateful for any advice on this subject. Or if there is no direct solution, maybe you know some workaround. Thank you for any information in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using font-feature-settings? IE10 supports this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869409(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: IcoMoon mentions that ligatures are not supported in IE9 and older: http://icomoon.io/#docs/ligatures :(

Comment: For anyone using ligatures for named icons (e.g. the Material Design icon set), note that if the ligature sequence is *exactly* 16 characters long, it won't render in IE. Thanks to Fordi [1] for calling this out [1] https://stackoverflow.com/users/353872/fordi

Answer (score 4):

Ligatures won't work in versions prior to IE10 using `-ms-font-feature-settings`

There really isn't an reliable method for cross browser ligatures with older browsers.

With CSS3 text-rendering: `optimizeLegibility` doesn't work in IE and ms-font-feature-settings is only supported as of IE10.

One alternative is to just use HTML entities, but then you're replacing letters with characters which would have a negative effect on SEO.

Ligature.js ([link](https://code.google.com/p/ligature-js/)) is an alternative way to add ligature support. It's better than just using HTML entities, but it's not very practical for other reasons.

This is an [excellent article](http://adamdscott.com/typography/ligatures-on-the-web/) that details the existing solutions and describes the CSS3 ligature handling for modern browsers.

Comment: Just my 2 cents: although common ligatures should be enabled by default, they only appeared in IE10+ after adding `font-feature-settings: "liga" 1;` and `-ms-font-feature-settings: "liga" 1;` as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings).